# numexpr malicious attack safety

Tags: security, numexpr

Is [numexpr](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) safe again malicious attack?

I'm considering using it in a web application, to evaluate user input text.

I've also considered using [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), [ASTEVAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asteval) and [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: I am also very curious about [numexpr](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) and [asteval](http://newville.github.io/asteval/)? Hasn't anyone an opinion or experience about these packages? There's no end to the [eval is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) talk. [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/index.html) may also be susceptible to malicious attack.